# Vue.js prevent v-link

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a table that looks like this:

[image]

The code looks like this:

```
<div class="Topic__item__body" v-for="topic in topics" v-link="{ name: 'Messages', params: { topic: topic.slug }}">
    <div class="Topic__item__body_content">
        <p class="Topic__title">{{ topic.name }}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Topic__item__body_content">
        <p>Berichten: 6</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Topic__item__body_content">
        <p>Door: Name lastname</p>
        <i class="material-icons Hearth" @click="test">&#xE87E;</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

So how can I make sure that when the user clicks on the material hearth icon, it does not link to `v-link="{ name: 'Messages', params: { topic: topic.slug }}"` but goes to the method `test`?

Comment: add an [event modifier](http://vuejs.org/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) to your handler, `@click.prevent="test"`

Answer (score 0):

To call a method on click you do it like this:

```
<i @click="test">&#xE87E;</i>
```

to call a link registered in `vue-router` you do it like

```
<router-link :to="{ path: 'home' }"><i @click="test">&#xE87E;</i></router-link>
```